# Google security warning on rclone

Tags: malware, google, opensource

I am setting up some new configurations with rclone to backup stuff to google drive. I am configuring application with the steps on https://rclone.org/drive/#making-your-own-client-id

When I am going through google's oauth process, I am presented with a warning from google [image]

I have got the binary from rclone's github release page. Should I still be worried about malware in the app, or google is just being paranoid ?

Update:I also setup another config for onedrive, but didn't see any warning from Microsoft.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore this warning